# Installing Windows 8.1 after Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

So I'm new to *Ubuntu* and I want to dual boot it with *Windows 8.1*.So first I installed my Ubuntu in my laptop and it is installed successfully(I think) so it's working well now. I have my *Windows 8.1* in my *flashdrive* and when I try to run the `setup.exe` I got this error:

> An error occurred while loading your archive

And so my question now:

1. Is it the same to make a dual boot from Windows to Ubuntu? (Because mostly what I've searched is **FROM** *Windows to Ubuntu*) and in my case is *Ubuntu to Windows* (I installed Ubuntu first because IN Windows normally the second OS will be the primary OS) e.g. when Windows is installed and you try to install Ubuntu and so the priority OS now will be Ubuntu. And I want to boot automatically to Windows that's why I installed the Ubuntu first.
2. How to install *Windows 8.1* now after installing Ubuntu?
3. How to make partition in *Ubuntu* ?

Comment: Have you tried booting from the USB drive?

Comment: @TimothyDuane: Not yet sir when I installed Ubuntu I think the OS get all the partition. I mean it only has one partition. Do you think if I boot it will also have a `custom` partition? Sorry just a noob question.

Comment: @TimothyDuane: How can I partition my `Internal Drive?`

Comment: You can use [GParted live-cd](http://gparted.org/download.php) or your Ubuntu live-cd [How to Resize Partitions with the Ubuntu or GParted Live CD](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd) for resizing and don't forget to **make a backup** before changing partitions. Look also at these links [Install Win8 After Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78054/install-win8-after-ubuntu) and [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

split your harddrive(using Hirens BootDisk setup - to resize the partition) and leave an unallocated space enough for windows 8.1 or whatever suits you

Then Create a Bootable FlashDrive with Windows 8.1 using Rufus preferebly or something that can create a bootable flash drive

Its worth a try worked for me

Comment: Any links for `Hirens BootDisk`?

Comment: Hirens BootDisk Link  - https://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/hirens-boot-dvd-15-2-restored-edition-free-download-7650836/